# How to read the soap data in web service?

Tags: c#, soap, service

How to access or read the data passed to the web service , data send to web service is in the form of SOAP  ?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question correctly you are trying to intercept the data that is being sent to the webservice.

If this is true, then you could use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), it's a tool that works as a proxy between you and network and is able to intercept messages being sent.

After you have finished install you would need to run fiddler then make a call from your application to web service and then find the url of webservice in the list of calls (left window). Click on that url on the right window will open. (Top) Click on the tab `Inspectors` -> `Raw`  this should show you the data that has been sent to web service and on the bottom window by clicking `Raw` you can see what did web service responded with.
Check screenshot below.

[image]